# merging multiple columns into one columns in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, stack, concatenation

I have a dataframe called ref(first  dataframe) with columns c1, c2 ,c3 and c4.

```
ref= pd.DataFrame([[1,3,.3,7],[0,4,.5,4.5],[2,5,.6,3]], columns=['c1','c2','c3','c4'])
print(ref)
   c1  c2   c3   c4
0   1   3  0.3  7.0
1   0   4  0.5  4.5
2   2   5  0.6  3.0
```

I wanted to create a new column i.e, c5 ( second dataframe) that has all the values from columns c1,c2,c3 and c4.

I tried concat, merge columns but i cannot get it work.

Please let me know if you have a solutions?

[image: pic]

Comment: why you need to append the column? the new column wont match the dimension

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) for creating `Series` from `DataFrame` and then [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) to original:

```
print (pd.concat([ref, ref.unstack().reset_index(drop=True).rename('c5')], axis=1))
     c1   c2   c3   c4   c5
0   1.0  3.0  0.3  7.0  1.0
1   0.0  4.0  0.5  4.5  0.0
2   2.0  5.0  0.6  3.0  2.0
3   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  3.0
4   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  4.0
5   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  5.0
6   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  0.3
7   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  0.5
8   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  0.6
9   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  7.0
10  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  4.5
11  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  3.0
```

Alternative solution for creating `Series` is convert `df` to `numpy array` by [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) and then reshape by [`ravel`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html):

```
    print (pd.concat([ref, pd.Series(ref.values.ravel('F'), name='c5')], axis=1))
         c1   c2   c3   c4   c5
    0   1.0  3.0  0.3  7.0  1.0
    1   0.0  4.0  0.5  4.5  0.0
    2   2.0  5.0  0.6  3.0  2.0
    3   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  3.0
    4   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  4.0
    5   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  5.0
    6   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  0.3
    7   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  0.5
    8   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  0.6
    9   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  7.0
    10  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  4.5
    11  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  3.0
```

Comment: Thank you for you time , answers and  your help.  I really appreciate it.

Comment: i am new to stackoverflow. how should i accept your answer? you mean click on the arrow button?

Comment: You need click to empty tick under `1` in upper left corner of answer - then tick is green.

Answer (score 3):

***using `join` + `ravel('F')`***

```
ref.join(pd.Series(ref.values.ravel('F')).to_frame('c5'), how='right')
```

***using `join` + `T.ravel()`***

```
ref.join(pd.Series(ref.values.T.ravel()).to_frame('c5'), how='right')
```

***`pd.concat` + `T.stack()` + `rename`***

```
pd.concat([ref, ref.T.stack().reset_index(drop=True).rename('c5')], axis=1)
```

***way too many transposes + `append`***

```
ref.T.append(ref.T.stack().reset_index(drop=True).rename('c5')).T
```

***`combine_first` + `ravel('F')`***  ***<--- my favorite***

```
ref.combine_first(pd.Series(ref.values.ravel('F')).to_frame('c5'))
```

---

All yield

```
     c1   c2   c3   c4   c5
0   1.0  3.0  0.3  7.0  1.0
1   0.0  4.0  0.5  4.5  0.0
2   2.0  5.0  0.6  3.0  2.0
3   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  3.0
4   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  4.0
5   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  5.0
6   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  0.3
7   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  0.5
8   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  0.6
9   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  7.0
10  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  4.5
11  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  3.0
```

Comment: Thank you for you time , answers and  your help.  I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

use the list(zip()) as follows:

```
d=list(zip(df1.c1,df1.c2,df1.c3,df1.c4))
df2['c5']=pd.Series(d)
```

Comment: have you tested it and works as expected? see OP image for example

Comment: Thank you for you time , answers and  your help.  I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

try this one, works as you expected
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5],[3,4,5,6]], columns=['c1','c2','c3','c4'])
print(df)
r = len(df['c1'])
c = len(list(df))

ndata = list(df.c1) + list(df.c2) + list(df.c3) + list(df.c4)
r = len(ndata) - r
t = r*c
dfnan = pd.DataFrame(np.reshape([np.nan]*t, (r,c)), columns=list(df))
df = df.append(dfnan)
df['c5'] = ndata
print(df)
```

output is below

[image]

Comment: Thank you for you time , answers and  your help.  I really appreciate it.

Comment: i am new to stackoverflow. how should i accept your answer? you mean click on the arrow button?

Answer (score 0):

This could be a fast option and maybe you can use it inside a loop.

```
import numpy as np

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5],[3,4,5,6]], columns=['c1','c2','c3','c4'])

df['c5'] = df.iloc[:,0].astype(str) + df.iloc[:,1].astype(str) + df.iloc[:,2].astype(str) + df.iloc[:,3].astype(str)
```

Greetings