# How do I get minimal value of multiple column timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp

I want to get minimal value of multiple column timestamp. Here's my data

```
Id      timestamp 1             timestamp 2             timestamp 3
136     2014-08-27 17:29:23     2014-11-05 13:02:18     2014-09-29 22:26:34
245     2015-09-06 15:46:00     NaN                     NaN
257     2014-09-29 22:26:34     2016-02-02 17:59:54     NaN
258     NaN                     NaN                     NaN
480     2016-02-02 17:59:54     2014-11-05 13:02:18     NaN
```

I want to get minimal timestamp of minimal

```
Id      minimal
136     2014-08-27 17:29:23
245     2015-09-06 15:46:00
257     2014-09-29 22:26:34
258     NaN
480     2014-11-05 13:02:18
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41627678/merging-multiple-columns-into-one-columns-in-pandas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select all columns without first by [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html), convert to `datetime`s and get `min` per rows and it is added to first column by [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df = df[['Id']].join(df.iloc[:, 1:].apply(pd.to_datetime).min(axis=1).rename('min'))
print (df)
    Id                 min
0  136 2014-08-27 17:29:23
1  245 2015-09-06 15:46:00
2  257 2014-09-29 22:26:34
3  258                 NaT
4  480 2014-11-05 13:02:18
```